# Why storing an rvalue reference in a variable can cause it to dangle

Tags: c++, rvalue-reference

I've got an abstract base class and some concrete subclasses:

```
class AbstractBaseClass {
private:
  bool destructed {};
public:
  virtual ~AbstractBaseClass() { destructed = true; }
  // returns false unless we're calling on already destructed value
  bool leaked() { return destructed; };
};

class ConcreteSubClassA : public AbstractBaseClass {
public:
  ~ConcreteSubClassA() override {}
};
class ConcreteSubClassB : public AbstractBaseClass {
public:
  ~ConcreteSubClassB() override {}
};
```

Can someone explain to me why the rvalue reference to the subclass instance
doesn't leak in these cases:

```
static_cast<AbstractBaseClass&&>(ConcreteSubClassA()).leaked(); // false

std::forward<AbstractBaseClass>(ConcreteSubClassA()).leaked(); // false

((rand() & 1)
 ? static_cast<AbstractBaseClass&&>(ConcreteSubClassA())
 : static_cast<AbstractBaseClass&&>(ConcreteSubClassB())
).leaked(); // false

((rand() & 1)
 ? std::forward<AbstractBaseClass>(ConcreteSubClassA())
 : std::forward<AbstractBaseClass>(ConcreteSubClassB())
).leaked(); // false

AbstractBaseClass&& abc = ConcreteSubClassA();
abc.leaked(); // false

AbstractBaseClass&& abc = static_cast<AbstractBaseClass&&>(ConcreteSubClassA());
abc.leaked(); // false
```

But does in these?

```
AbstractBaseClass&& abc = std::forward<AbstractBaseClass>(ConcreteSubClassA());
abc.leaked(); // true

AbstractBaseClass&& abc = (rand() & 1) 
  ? static_cast<AbstractBaseClass&&>(ConcreteSubClassA())
  : static_cast<AbstractBaseClass&&>(ConcreteSubClassB());
abc.leaked(); // true

AbstractBaseClass&& abc = (rand() & 1) 
  ? std::forward<AbstractBaseClass>(ConcreteSubClassA())
  : std::forward<AbstractBaseClass>(ConcreteSubClassB());
abc.leaked(); // true
```

That is, why the destructor is called so early?

Comment: Shouldn't leaked be !destructed?

Comment: `// returns false unless we're calling on already destructed value` Ehm, no... you're relying on undefined behaviour. You can't read a variable that no longer exists.

Comment: Jacques de Hooge: I'm using the definition that a reference leaks or dangles if it can be used after being destructed.

Comment: It can _never_ be used after being destructed. That your program compiles is not an indication to the contrary.

Comment: Lightness Races in Orbit: This is only for illustration purposes - it's easier than sticking a bunch of prints in the destructor and analyzing after the fact.

Comment: Then it is a very bad illustration.

Comment: This is using `Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.57) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)` with ` -std=c++1y -Wall -Wextra -Werror -g --stdlib=libc++`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125794/discussion-between-rampion-and-lightness-races-in-orbit).

Answer (score 3):

Temporaries are destroyed at the end of a full expression (unless when bound to references). This fact explains the direct uses of the temprories work.

When binding a temporary object *directly* to a reference, i.e., either a `const&` or a `&&`, its life-time gets extended to match the life-time of the reference. This is the reason your examples binding directly (or via a cast) to an rvalue work.

When binding an lvalue to a reference life-times do **not** get extended - the compiler can't be expected to see through the construct. It does **not** make a difference to cast the lvalue to an rvalue reference. Note that an rvalue reference is an lvalue.

Of course, your results for `leaked()` when returning `true` depend on undefined behavior: at the point the object is destroyed you can't touch it without invoking undefined behavior.

Comment: Ok. I remain confused by `AbstractBaseClass&& abc = ConcreteSubClassA(); abc.leaked(); // false`.  This is binding an lvalue to a reference, yes?  Is the seeming extended lifespan of the reference an illusion due to undefined behaviour?

Comment: No, it's binding an rvalue to a reference. `ConcreteSubClassA()` creates a temporary, i.e. rvalue, not an lvalue.

Comment: ok, I had the sense of that verb swapped around. So I don't get Dietmar Kühl's paragraph about "binding an lvalue to a reference" then. What lvalues am I binding in my examples?  Aren't `ConcreteSubClassA()`, `static_cast<AbstractBaseClass&&>(ConcreteSubClassA())`, and `std::forward<AbstractBaseClass>(ConcreteSubClassA())` all rvalues?

Comment: @rampion: no, they are not: `std::forward<T>(x)` always returns an lvalue. The returned lvalue may be an rvalue reference but the compiler isn't meant to see through that. I think it is required to see through a `static_cast`, however.

Comment: oh, I thought [`std::forward<T>(x)` returns `T&&`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward), which is an rvalue?

Comment: @rampion: a `T&&` isn't an rvalue. It is an lvalue. It just happens that this lvalue can only be initialized from an rvalue. This fact is more obvious with function parameters: clearly a `T&& x` (independent on whether the `T` is deduced, i.e., independent on whether it is forwarding or an rvalue reference) has a name (`x`) and, thus, is an lvalue. The same is true for results from functions, though. In fact, the entity `x` returned from `std::forward<T>(x)` clearly has a name, i.e., it is an lvalue. Just because it ends up cast to an rvalue reference doesn't change that.